# problem in directory mapping/config

Tags: php, directory

my index file is-

```
include("application.php");

$DOC_TITLE = "MyMarket Home";
include("$CFG->templatedir/header.php");
?>
//html page code

<?
include("$CFG->templatedir/footer.php");
?>
```

**application.php code-**

```
error_reporting(15);

/* define a generic object */
class object {};

$CFG = new object;

/* database configuration */
$CFG->dbhost = "localhost";
$CFG->dbname = "mymarket";
$CFG->dbuser = "root";
$CFG->dbpass = "";


$CFG->wwwroot     = "http://localhost/mymarket";
$CFG->dirroot     = dirname(__FILE__);
$CFG->templatedir = "$CFG->dirroot/templates";
$CFG->libdir      = "$CFG->dirroot/lib";
$CFG->imagedir    = "$CFG->wwwroot/images";
$CFG->icondir     = "$CFG->imagedir/icons";
$CFG->bannerdir   = "$CFG->imagedir/banners";
$CFG->support     = "support@mymarket.org";
$CFG->version     = "1.71";
$CFG->sessionname = "mymarket";

/* extended configuration */
$CFG->showsponsor   = true;     // enabled banner advertising
$CFG->currency      = "$";
$CFG->currencyfirst = true; // show the currency symbol before the price tag

/* define database error handling behavior, since we are in development stages
* we will turn on all the debugging messages to help us troubleshoot */
$DB_DEBUG = true;
$DB_DIE_ON_FAIL = true;

/* load up standard libraries */
require("$CFG->libdir/stdlib.php");
require("$CFG->libdir/dblib.php");
require("$CFG->libdir/mymarket.php");
require("$CFG->libdir/cart.php");
...
```

**>>** these files are inside xampp->htdocs->mymarket
but when I am trying to run application `index.php` page showing this error  **templatedir/header.php"); ?>

//html page

 templatedir/footer.php"); ?>**

and even shopping page is givin some error.some strating code-

```
include("../application.php");

$id = nvl($_REQUEST["id"], 1);
$qid_c = get_sub_categories($id);
$qid_p = get_products($id);

$DOC_TITLE = "Shopping Catalog";
include("$CFG->templatedir/header.php");
include("templates/catalog.php");
include("$CFG->templatedir/footer.php");
...
```

**I think I have set `$CFG->wwwroot` and `$CFG->dirroot` variables properly thats why this directory mapping problem is coming.**

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be something like this?

> include("{$CFG->templatedir}/header.php");

or

> include($CFG->templatedir . "/header.php");